# JSON data getting lost during Zip

Tags: c#, json, zip, json.net

I have a most bizarre issue. I have a bunch of objects that I am trying to store in JSON format. The file that contains the JSON will be placed in a zip archive along with any resources the project references. When I serialize the objects into JSON it's fine, but once the file gets archived then extracted, some of the fields just vanish.

My code:

```
string root = Path.GetTempPath() + "package_root\\";

string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(root + "contents.json", contents);

byte[] buf;

 _ParseResource(root, package, package.BackgroundImage);
foreach (var resource in package.Resources)
{
    _ParseResource(root, package, resource);
}

if (package.PackagePath == path)
{
    package.Archive.Dispose();
    package.Archive = null;
}

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(root, outputPath, CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);
```

JSON before zipping:

```
{
    "Nodes":[
    {
        "NodeID": 0,
        "NodeType": 1,
        "Position": "0.0537248952329852,0.460410557184751",
        "ActionType": "SimpleTextImageAction",
        "Metadata": {
            "ImageID": -1,
            "Text": "",
            "MetadataTypeID": 2,
            "Tooltip": null
        }
    }
    ],
    "Resources":[],
    "PackageVersion": 1.0,
    "BackgroundImage": {
        "ResourceID": -1,
        "Path": "C:\\Users\\Abion47-SSD\\Desktop\\Panorama Images\\89_-_Machu_Picchu_-_Juin_2009.jpg",
        "Type": 1,
        "CacheOnLoad": true,
        "Origin": 2
    }
}
```

JSON after zipping:

```
{  
    "Nodes":[  
    {  
        "NodeType":1,
        "Position":"0.0801201698474518,0.294721407624633",
        "ActionType":"SimpleTextAction",
        "Metadata":{  
            "Text":"Tooltip",
            "Tooltip":null
        }
    }
    ],
    "Resources":[],
    "PackageVersion":1.0,
    "BackgroundImage":{  
        "ResourceID":-1,
        "Path":"C:\\Users\\Abion47\\Desktop\\Panorama Files\\89_-_Machu_Picchu_-_Juin_2009.jpg",
        "Type":1,
        "CacheOnLoad":true,
        "Origin":2
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Abion, could you please include the name and version and library you're using to do the zipping and unzipping? If possible, could you also edit your code down to simply `var content = [your json]; Zip(); Unzip();`? It'll make it 1) Easier for everyone to diagnose the actual issue and 2) Make it easier for answers to simply copy + paste your code to replicate the issue.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue on my machine - it's returning the same json. Are you sure you're opening the same archive that you've just written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Here's the code I'm using to (attempt) to reproduce it:

```
string root = Path.GetTempPath() + "package_root\\";

string contents = 
@"{
""Nodes"":[
{
    ""NodeID"": 0,
    ""NodeType"": 1,
    ""Position"": ""0.0537248952329852,0.460410557184751"",
    ""ActionType"": ""SimpleTextImageAction"",
    ""Metadata"": {
        ""ImageID"": -1,
        ""Text"": """",
        ""MetadataTypeID"": 2,
        ""Tooltip"": null
    }
}
],
""Resources"":[],
""PackageVersion"": 1.0,
""BackgroundImage"": {
    ""ResourceID"": -1,
    ""Path"": ""C:\\Users\\Abion47-SSD\\Desktop\\Panorama Images\\89_-_Machu_Picchu_-_Juin_2009.jpg"",
    ""Type"": 1,
    ""CacheOnLoad"": true,
    ""Origin"": 2
}
}";

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(root + "contents.json"), contents);

/* SNIP resource inclusion */

if (!Directory.Exists(root))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(root);

var outDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "outDir");
if (!Directory.Exists(outDir))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outDir);

var outZipFullPath = Path.Combine(outDir, "out.zip");
if (File.Exists(outZipFullPath))
    File.Delete(outZipFullPath);

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(root, outZipFullPath, CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);

var outContentsFile = Path.Combine(outDir, "contents.json");

if (File.Exists(outContentsFile))
    File.Delete(outContentsFile);

ZipFile.Open(outZipFullPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read).Entries.First().ExtractToFile(outContentsFile);

Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(outContentsFile) == contents);
```

Prints `true` for me. It's quite likely you're opening and comparing the wrong zip file

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out I was looking in a different but very similarly named folder.